# Why there are indents in the table list?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I take Api data and output their to the page as a table-list in my React-Redux app.

it should look like this:

[image]
But I got it like this:

[image]
Ignore the different colors. The problem is that my gray line breaks. I don't need indents.Also line should also be up to the end of the width of the white container.What can be the problem? And how to fix it?

TableData.js(component which displays the data on the page):

```
import React from "react";

export default ({ data }) => (
     <div className="tableContainer">
  <table className="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Terminal</th>
        <th>Gate</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Destination</th>
        <th>Airline</th>
        <th>Flight</th>
        <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {data.map(item => {
         const dt = new Date(item.actual);
         const mins = dt.getMinutes();
        return (
          <tr key={item.ID}>
            <td>{item.term}</td>
            <td>{item.gateNo}</td>
            <td>{`${dt.getHours()}:${mins < 10 ? '0' : ''}${mins}`}</td>
            <td>
              {item["airportToID.city_en"]
                ? item["airportToID.city_en"]
                : item["airportFromID.city_en"]}
            </td>
            <td>{item.airline.en.name}</td>
            <td>{item["planeTypeID.code"]}</td>
            <td>{item.status}</td>
          </tr>
        );
      })}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
);
```

app.css(style):

```
/*Table*/
.tableContainer{
    background: white;
    width: 800px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: left;
}

table td,table th {
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 18px;

}
th {
    color: grey;
}

.tableContainer tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: grey;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use { border-spacing: 0px } for table

Comment: Thunks, and why is white 1 centimeter to the right of status?

Comment: Try  table {
  width: 100%;
 } - I think the problem is that . tableContainer has 800px width and table doesn't fill it all

Comment: Thunks very much!

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot

```
table {
  border: 0px
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

See https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_border-spacing

Comment: Thunks, and why is white 1 centimeter to the right of status?

Comment: http://i.piccy.info/i9/785ff54847f2c78103cba42f76e14a33/1573515039/49131/1334636/Screenshot_36.jpg